# Excel formula for checking items that are 24 hours old

Tags: excel, countif

I'm looking for an excel formula that will count items in a column that are less than 24 hours from now().

I have a column where I keep my medicine dosages and need to have a field that tallies just the doses I've taken within the last 24 hours always.

thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Simply subtracting 1 from NOW() will give you exactly 24 hours ago.  So your formula will look like

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A4,">"&NOW()-1)
```

Be sure to replace A2:A4 with the range of the cells with values you would like to count.